# can't find error in code

Tags: c

I write encrypted\decrypted system (prototype).
This system have packet on 188 byte. And scrambling:

Encrypted(Python):

```
#key = 40
packet[4]+packet[40:]+packet[4:40]
```

Decrypted(C):

```
//in_buffer - main char* massive
//offs - offset of packet (length 188)
//key - int for separator (40 in example before)

void encryption(byte* in_buffer, int offs, int key)
{
  byte temp[188];
  int i;
  //write packet[4:40] to temp
  for(i = 4;i < key; i++)
  {  
    temp[i] = in_buffer[offs+i];
  }
  //write packet[40:] to top
  for(i = 4;i < 188 - key+4; i++)
  {  
    in_buffer[offs+i] = in_buffer[offs+i+key-4];
  }
  //write packet[4:40] of temp to in_buffer[152:]
  for(i = 4;i < key; i++)
  {  
    in_buffer[offs+i+188-key] = temp[i];
  }
}
```

It works for key = 96, but don't work for any other key! Why?

Comment: And that's why I hate Google Translate...

Comment: MPEG-TS, perchance? (Just guessing)

Comment: Also, seriously, use `memcpy` instead of a loop.

Comment: Yes, i'm tried debuggind. All right. And yes, this is MPEG-TS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that array subscript arithmetic is nasty and error-prone. Use `memcpy` to "append" the various parts into place:

```
byte temp[188];
int pos = 0;

memcpy(temp + pos, in_buffer, 4); // append in_buffer[:4]
pos += 4;
memcpy(temp + pos, in_buffer + 188 - key + 4, key - 4); // append in_buffer[188-key+4:188]
pos += key-4;
memcpy(temp + pos, in_buffer + 4, 188 - key); // append in_buffer[4:188-key+4]
```